# Python alpha_vantage module not returning all quotes for 'get_batch_stock_quotes'

Tags: python3

When using [alpha_vantage](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage#notification-settings) to pull batch stock quotes for some reason `get_batch_stock_quotes` does not return the quote for symbol "ARRS".  However, if the function is called using only "ARRS" in the symbols list, the quote is returned.  I don't want to make several individual calls if I can get all the quotes returned in one request.

Here's the test code:

```
import pandas as pd

from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

import time

api_key = '12BHXD9VVA9M1PUM'

ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format = 'pandas')

stocklist = ("ARRS","PCG","AAPL","ACB")

STOCK=""
PRICE=0

data, meta_data =ts.get_batch_stock_quotes(symbols=stocklist)


for label, row in data.iterrows():

    STOCK=row[0]
    PRICE=p=round(float(row[1]),2)

    print (STOCK,PRICE)
```

Results:

```
$ python3 test8.py

PCG 11.67
AAPL 212.3
ACB 5.79
```

If I just use  `stocklist = ("ARRS")`
the result is:

```
$ python3 test8.py

ARRS 31.64
```

Why does this happen?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen?

Unfortunately, this seems to possibly be something specific to your environment. Copying and pasting your code on Windows 7 with Python 3.7.4 yielded all four symbols with prices, as expected:

```
ARRS 31.64
PCG 11.03
AAPL 202.79
ACB 5.64
```